# Rating Listed backwards on capacitor?

Tags: capacitor

I understand the ratings on capacitors but when checking this one and noticed that instead of it saying 40/5uF it was written backwards as 5/40uF. I am not in the HVAC trade but never saw that before and assume its just how that manufacture labels their capacitor. But thought I should check if there is something about this one that I dont know.
Based on the picture, does this just use a standard 40+5uF 440v capacitor?
Thanks!
[image]

Comment: This might be better on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/  They should have someone better to know if it makes a difference, or as you think just weird labelling.

Comment: That seems to be more about micro electronics and this is more of an HVAC question which is why I thought the diy home repair area is better for it. Thanks.

Comment: They should have more knowledge of capacitors, where we are more of a replace with same.  Usually labels are done to a standard that means something.

Comment: have you googled the part number that's printed on the cap?

Comment: Of course. :) cant find that part number. at least nothing that shows the microfarad's backwards like that. I dont think it means anything but was hoping someone who knows more could confirm that.

Comment: Searching for 5/40uf does show a capacitor with similar part number, missing a J(adds an R) and i.  As far as I know(very little) it should work, but connections/size/shape might be different.

Answer (score 1):

A major capacitor maker in their excellent 20 page brochure on types of capacitors and their uses states:

> Dual and Triple Section Capacitors:
> Multi-section capacitors are nothing more than two or three separate capacitor in a common enclosure with
> one common terminal. They are marked with the voltage rating and the mfd for each section.
> Example: 20/4 mfd 370 vol

They label their dual-section capacitors with the larger value first, as you mentioned.

In the case of your capacitor (guessing only), perhaps the "standard" positions in the outer can of the two internal capacitors are switched, so the terminals on top corresponding to each of the two are also switched vs. standard dual capacitors.

Comment: This sounds reasonable, however, would hooking it up incorrectly (assuming that the connections are "backwards" from what would normally be expected) cause problems? I'm decent with electrical, but rubbish with electronics, so I haven't a clue.

Comment: @FreeMan According to the capacitor maker's booklet, yes, it could lead to motor damage or a fire if the wrong capacitance (essentially charge storage capacity) was used, depending on which part of the motor's circuit it was connected to. This is definitely old-school analog electrical engineering.